# how to prove that $f(n)=n^3+n\log^2n$ = $\theta(n^3)$?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

i have   $f(n)=n^3+n\log^2n$ 
and i was trieng to prove that $f(n)=n^3+n\log^2n$ = $\theta(n^3)$. but i feel that i am doing it all wrong , which means i understand why the statent is true but i don't know if the way i proved it was enough..
here is what i did so far :

first i need to prove that :
 $f(n)=n^3+n\log^2n$ = $O(n^3)$
    We can choose constant C like this : if we devide the equation with $n^3$ then we get : $1+n\log^2n/n^3$ $<=$ $C $  but $n\log^2n/n^3$ <= 1 for every n so if we choose C to be C>=2 then this will be proved.

second i need to prove :$f(n)=n^3+n\log^2n$ = $pi(n^3)$
this i think doesn't need to be proved because if i choose any  C<1 then for every n we will get : $n^3+n\log^2n$ >= $C(n^3)$

here is

Comment: What are $\theta$ and pi?..... BTW the codes \le  and \leq  give $\le$ while \ge and \geq give $\ge$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log n}{\sqrt n} = (\infty / \infty)           = (by L'Hospital) \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{2\sqrt n}{n} =0$

Comment: i didn't really understand the hint .. is this a way toprove that nlog2n/n3 <= 1 ?

Comment: @jasmin: basically, $\log n$ grows slower than $\sqrt n$ so $\log^2 n$ grows slower than $n$ which means $n\log^2 n/n^3< 1/n  \le 1$

Comment: To the proposer: For any positive $A,B$ we have $ \lim_{x\to \infty}(\ln x)^A/x^B=0.$